# Problems with :before and :after in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element, before-filter

This basically adds two lines before and after the h1 element, like this:
The line is just a background color with a height of 1px.

------------------------ Some Text ------------------------

I tested this in Chrome and Firefox and everything works properly but when I test it in Internet Explorer 10 the LEFT line is not displayed.

```css
.ItemHeader div h1 {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.ItemHeader div h1:before, .ItemHeader div h1:after {
    top: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 1px;
    content:"\a0";
    background-color:#a2a2a2;
    position: absolute;
    width:50%;
}
.ItemHeader div h1:before {
    margin-left:-51%;
    text-align: right;
}
.ItemHeader div h1:after {
    margin-left:1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-block">
    <div class="ItemHeader">
        <div>
            <h1>Application</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Checkout the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KX3u/1/)

Comment: ahaaaa. I see your trouble. Now I'm working on it Mr. Eric Bergman. lol... like Cartman. =))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```css
.ItemHeader div h1 {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.ItemHeader div h1:before, .ItemHeader div h1:after {
    top: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 1px;
    content:"\a0";
    background-color:#a2a2a2;
    position: absolute;
    width:50%;
}
.ItemHeader div h1:before {
    left:-5%;
    text-align: right;
}
.ItemHeader div h1:after {
    left:55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-block">
    <div class="ItemHeader">
        <div>
            <h1>Application</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Remove the `margin-left` properties in your code and use `left` instead.

It's working fine in both Chrome and IE10.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4KX3u/7/

Comment: The problem with using "left" isntead of margins is that the lines intersect with the text if the text length changes but with margins it doesn't happen.

Comment: Here's the problem with using left, I changed the text to a longer one: http://jsfiddle.net/4KX3u/9/

Comment: But Mr. Bergman,

You're using absolute values: http://jsfiddle.net/4KX3u/11/

Phew =)